# Does assuming a normal distribution for a sample mean the sample comes from a normal distribution?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, descriptive-statistics

As my question says, I am wondering what people mean when they say the data follows a normal distribution, does this mean the population follows a normal distribution?

Answer (score 2):

A sample *can’t* be normal!

Samples are necessarily finite. A normal distribution can take on infinitely many values, so a sample can’t be normal.

Therefore, when we say that we have points that are distributed normally, we mean that they come from a normal population.

Comment: If we assume that the data is normally distributed meaning the data come from a normal distribution, then do we need to perform the normality check?

Comment: Your options are to: 1) proceed with the assumption 2) check if your assumption is a good one.

Comment: I am wondering if we need a normality check if we assume the data are normally distributed.

Comment: I would like to check if my assumption is a reasonable one. // You're still learning, so please be careful with terminology so you know what's really happening. The data *can't* be normal; the data could be drawn from a normal population distribution, however.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to guess, where your problem lies, but it seems to me that you have not yet grasped the concept of a *sample*. The statistical model underlying this concept is as follows:

1. A numeric result of a random experiment follows a certain probability distribution.
2. The random experiment is repeated *independently* $n$ times
3. The list of results $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ is called a "sample".

The distribution in 1. can be a normal distribution, which is the case to which you refer.